# Using the for loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

I'm trying to python for loop and dictionary.

trying to do the following, please help me.

```
{
   a : {
         'a' : 'b'
         'a' : 'c'
         'a' : 'd'
             ....
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with *trying to do the following?* There is no input/output...

Comment: Plus there is no way to have a dictionary with several times the same key...

Comment: i understand.. i will closed the this question 
reply thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Example :

```
d={'a': {'1': 'a1', '2' :'a2'}, 'b' : { '1' : 'b1', '2' : 'b2'}}
```

The for loop :

```
for k1 in d:
    for k2 in d[k1]:
        print "k1=%s, k2=%s, value=%s" % (k1, k2, d[k1][k2])
```

Result :

```
k1=a, k2=1, value=a1
k1=a, k2=2, value=a2
k1=b, k2=1, value=b1
k1=b, k2=2, value=b2
```